# Cannot boot into GUI

Tags: boot, gpu

Cannot boot into GUI at all. Was working for awhile but I think something happened awhile back, when I plugged my TV into the HDMI port on my laptop. After trying a ton of solutions like un/re/installing lightdm, gdm, and other things, I was able to install gnome from the command line and start that GUI from tty1, but now that doesn't work again and I may have narrowed it down to my GPU configuration. When I run the command

```
sudo lshw -c video | grep 'configuration'
```

I get

```
configuration: latency=0
configuration: latency=0
```

Nothing is currently plugged into the HDMI port. I'm fairly new at command line stuff, so please take that into account. I can get into tty1 but the normal boot process hangs at "device for cryptswap1...".